# Unable to delete object that used strcpy()

Tags: c++, exception, memory, strcpy

Recently I was deleting an object and an exception would get thrown, and I have narrowed it down to the use of strcpy(). To test this, I made a simple test class that uses (basically) only strcpy() and voila, an exception.

```
#pragma once
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(char []);
    ~TestClass();

    char teststring[];
};
```

It's constructor looks like this:

```
TestClass::TestClass(char incstring[])
{
    strcpy(teststring, incstring);
    printf(teststring);
}
```

If I run the following code:

```
int main(){
    TestClass* test = new TestClass("Cheezit");

    delete test;
}
```

I get a thrown exception! What is HAPPENING WITH STRCPY()??!?!?!?!

Note: The console window does print "Cheezit".

Comment: That is not a valid class definition. Your code is not valid C++; you are very unlucky to be using a broken compiler (or using a compiler in a broken way) that it lets you get away with this.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: @Slava: it probably is. This looks like a C flexible array member, strangely permitted in C++.

Comment: How does it work in C?

Comment: @Slava: It's called a "[flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)". You can only use it in dynamic allocation contexts.

Comment: If you are using GCC, add the -pedantic flag. Also, I really doubt that an exception is being thrown. You are almost certainly getting a segmentation fault or something similar - these are not exceptions in the C++ sense.

Comment: The code is not a MCVE, since it lacks the needed `#include`s and the definition of `~TestClass`.

Comment: The problem is not `strcpy`, the problem is that you write to `test->teststring` which doesn't have memory to hold `"Cheezit"`.

Comment: Does not compile on gcc http://ideone.com/Z1JY2J

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not valid C++. In C++, all non-static class data members must have *complete* type, and `char[]` is not a complete type. You need to specify the array size, and then initialize the array accordingly:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(char a[]) : teststring{} { std::strncpy(teststring, a, 2); }
    char teststring[3];
};
```

You cannot deduce the array size from any constructor, because the constructor is *part of the class*, and the class is not complete until the array size has been specified.

Comment: With C++17 he could make it a template class and have the size deduced: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: Sure, but that's something completely different... (And you wouldn't deduce of a constructor parameter *value*!)

Comment: @KerrekSB thank you, I have since changed teststring to a char pointer (char*) and in TestClass's constructor I have a line just before strcpy() that reads: "teststring = new char[sizeof(incstring)];". Will this make teststring point to an array the size of incstring? and is this memory safe?

Comment: @DanielOelbaum: It is none of these things. Every single thing you said has a bug in it. Update your question and I can point them out. Or just look on this website, search for "array size" and "sizeof". And look up how null-terminated strings work and how `strcpy` works.

Comment: I did some research and think I have made some progress. I have posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531933/using-passed-in-array-to-initialize-other-array. if any of you could help me out there, I would appreciate it greatly

Comment: @DanielOelbaum: Yeah, I saw... to be honest, there is just *so much* wrong with that code, it's really hard to point out in a brief answer. I could probably spend a whole hour dissecting that code... maybe someone will post a longer review answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
char teststring[];
```

as an array member is not allowed in Standard C++.

Your compiler appears to be treating it as a Flexible Array Member, a feature from C, as an extension to C++.  However, using a Flexible Array Member correctly requires some care with allocation, which you have not done.  So even supposing there is some such extension, your program still has undefined behavior.