# Using passed-in array to initialize other array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, strcpy

I am trying to "initialize" an array that I have made in my class declaration and I do not know what I am doing wrong. I understand that when you pass an array into a function, it decays into a pointer to the first character. The code breaks on my second strcpy() line but I am not sure what it is I am doing wrong (I have very little experience with strcpy()).

My code reads as follows:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(char []);
    ~TestClass();
    void Append(TestClass);

    char* m_string;
};

TestClass::TestClass(char incstring[])
{
    char currentChar = 'a';
    int numOfChars = 0;

    while (currentChar != '\0') {
        currentChar = *(incstring + numOfChars);
        numOfChars++;
    }

    char* tmp = new char[numOfChars-1];
    strcpy(tmp, incstring);
    strcpy(m_string, tmp);
}
```

My int main() is simply:

```
int main(){
    TestClass* test = new TestClass("Hello");
}
```

If it is worth noting, numOfChars is equal to 6, as it correctly should be.

The exception thrown is: " Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD. "

Comment: `m_string` is never initialized.

Comment: Please use `std::string` and save yourself the trouble.  Also, there's no good reason for `new` in your `main`: `TestClass test("Hello");` would do just as well without the memory leak.

Comment: I just initialized it to nullptr, and get the same exception.

Comment: The point Kerrek is trying to make is that you are not allocating any memory for `m_string` before you copy data from `tmp` to `m_string`. That is why you crash.

Comment: @aschepler I would, but my specification warrents that I cannot use std containers

Comment: A pointer can only point to existing memory locations, it cannot store new data unless memory has been allocated for the data. This is why @KerrekSB is telling you your m_string pointer has not been initialized.

Comment: @RemyLebeau wow, I see what you guys mean. thank you so much, I added an alloc line and now it works great.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allocating any memory for `m_string` before you copy data from `tmp` to `m_string`.  That is why you are crashing.  `m_string` is not pointing at a valid memory address.

Since you have already allocated `tmp` and you are not going to use it anymore, you can just assign the `tmp` pointer directly to `m_string` without performing another copy.

Also, note that your `while` loop is duplicating what `strlen()` already does, so you should just use `strlen()`.

Try this:

```
TestClass::TestClass(char incstring[])
    : m_string(new char[strlen(incstring)+1])
{
    strcpy(m_string, incstring);
}

TestClass::~TestClass()
{
    delete[] m_string;
}
```

Which can be simplified using `strdup()` instead (use `free()` instead of `delete[]` to deallocate it):

```
TestClass::TestClass(char incstring[])
    : m_string(strdup(incstring))
{
}

TestClass::~TestClass()
{
    free(m_string);
}
```

With that said, your `main()` is leaking memory, as you are not freeing the `test` object:

```
int main(){
    TestClass* test = new TestClass("Hello");
    //...
    delete test; // <-- add this
}
```

Or simply:

```
int main(){
    TestClass test("Hello");
}
```

And lastly, make sure you implement the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) in your class.  You are managing dynamic memory that is freed in the destructor, so you also need a copy constructor and a copy assignment operation to ensure the integrity of `m_string` when creating `TestClass` values from other `TestClass` values:

```
class TestClass
{
private:
    char* m_string;

public:
    TestClass(char *incstring = 0);
    TestClass(const TestClass &src);
    ~TestClass();

    void Append(const TestClass &str);
    void Swap(TestClass &Other);

    TestClass& operator=(const TestClass &lhs);
};

TestClass::TestClass(char *incstring)
    : m_string(0)
{
    if (incstring)
    {
        m_string = new char[strlen(incstring)+1];
        strcpy(m_string, incstring);
    }
}

TestClass::TestClass(const TestClass &src)
    : m_string(0)
{
    if (src.m_string)
    {
        m_string = new char[strlen(src.m_string)+1];
        strcpy(m_string, src.m_string);
    }
}

TestClass::~TestClass()
{
    delete[] m_string;
}

void TestClass::Append(const TestClass &str)
{
    if (str.m_string)
    {
        TestClass tmp;
        tmp.m_string = new char[strlen(m_string)+strlen(str.m_string)+1];
        strcpy(tmp.m_string, m_string);
        strcat(tmp.m_string, str.m_string);
        Swap(tmp);
    }
}

void TestClass::Swap(TestClass &Other)
{
    char *ptr = m_string;
    m_string = Other.m_string;
    Other.m_string = ptr;
}

TestClass& TestClass::operator=(const TestClass &lhs)
{
    if (this != &lhs) {
        TestClass(lhs).Swap(*this);
    }    
    return *this;
}
```